# OAuth2 Code Parsing Problem in Xcode 11 and Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11, swift5

I'm working on a school project where I need to implement OAuth2 to get access to our student profiles and display them. The app has two views - a search bar and detailed user info on the next page.  I'm fairly new to this, so any advice will be greatly appreciated.

I was mostly following this tutorial https://grokswift.com/alamofire-OAuth2/ but a lot of stuff is deprecated. I can easily get all data using postman and user credentials but when I implement  OAuth2 I can't parse the code I receive. So all my functions are in ContentView (pretty sure it's not the right way, but I couldn't make it work otherwise for now). I have a search button that looks like this:

```
Button(
            action: {self.handleAPI()},
            label: {
                Text("Search")
        }
```

And a handleAPI function that calls other functions, and func startOAuth2Login() among them:

```
 if let authURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: authPath)
       {
            UIApplication.shared.open(authURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            print("here1")
       }
```

Everything works as expected, redirects me to the login screen, where I enter my credentials, press "Authorize" and successfully return to the app. The print statement is also visible. However, I can't find the link I receive to parse the auth code. I know it should be in AppDelegate and this is what I have for now but it's not being called.

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    ContentView.sharedInstance.processOAuthStep1Response(url: url as NSURL)
    print("url: \(url)")
    return true
}
```

processOAuthStep1Response(url) is just another function in my handleAPI main function. I also have this line in my ContentView : static let sharedInstance = ContentView().

So the question is how to call my function that will parse the code? How can I even see this code? XCode doesn't give any errors and everything works, just after "here1" nothing else is called. Thank you in advance!